# How to get symbol and price to show individually in a listview on xamarin c#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

How to get symbol in one label and the price in another label in xamrain c#
What i need help on is how i can make the symbol and the price be together in a listview for all the different coins. You can see in the link under GetPrice different symbols and different prices. I just want to put them in groups and seperate them in a listview. Please help me.

This is my MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Crypto_Portfolio.MainPage">
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
        <ListView x:Name="priceList">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                  <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding symbol}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding price}" />
                  </StackLayout>
               </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End">
        <Button Clicked="priceClick" Text="Fetch Price" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Crypto_Portfolio
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetPrice();
        }

        public class Crypto
        {
            public string symbol { get; set; }
            public string price { get; set; }
        }

        private async void GetPrice()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price");
            var cryptoconverted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Crypto>>(response);
            priceList.ItemsSource = cryptoconverted;
        }

        void priceClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetPrice();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: There is no ListView in your code, and only one label.  Do you expect us to write all of that for you?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "make the symbol and the price be together in a listview for all the different coins." ?

Comment: @Jason Sorry I'm new to this. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Cfun you can see in the link under GetPrice different symbols and different prices. I just want to put them in groups and seperate them in a listview.

Comment: there are many excellent tutorials on the Xamarin site, including multiple complete sample apps.  I suggest you take the time to review what's available

Comment: I suggest you to start the documentation, understand it, make your attempt and after that if not succeed ask a specific question, your current question is broad. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

Comment: why did you remove your button that calls GetPrice?  You either need to put that back, or call GetPrice from the OnAppearing method

Comment: @Jason I got it. Thank you so much

Comment: @Jason Another quesion, how do I get a only a specific symbol and price such as BTCUSDT and its price to show?

Comment: read the API docs on how to request a specific symbol, or use LINQ to filter the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to **deserialize** the json from the webservice into a C# class.  You can use [json2csharp.com](https://json2csharp.com/) to to this

```
public class Stock
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
}
```

then in your `GetPrice` method

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price");
var stocks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stock>>(response);
```

next, add a `ListView` to your XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="stockList">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding symbol}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding price}" />
          </StackLayout>
       </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

finally, assign your data to the `ListView` in `GetPrice`

```
stockList.ItemsSource = stocks
```

Comment: Honestly I learnt from you more than my teacher at school in 15 minutes. I honestly appreciate all your help sir.

Comment: @TejasSethi Seems that Jason's reply help you, please remember to mark this reply as answer, it is beneficial to other communities.